# Why my simple Struts2 hello world is not working?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2

I have created a simple struts2 project.

First, I add this to web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is my complete Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>pos</display-name>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Second, I create `struts.xml` to src

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
    <struts>
        <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="index" class="nerdy.action.IndexAction" method="index">
                <result name="success">/index/index.jsp</result>
            </action>        
        </package>
    </struts>
```

Finally, I create the package and class in src, and copy Struts2's jar to lib

```
    package nerdy.action;
    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class IndexAction extends ActionSupport {

      public String index() {
        return "success";
      }

    }
```

I run the server and tried these url

localhost:8080/pos/index.action

localhost:8080/index.action

localhost:8080/pos/indexaction

localhost:8080/pos/index

localhost:8080/pos/action

But all display 404: The requested resource is not available.

I checked that all name are match, and class is compiled in `build\classes`, and the index.jsp is in `WebContent/index/`

Is there any mistake still in my config? and why the URL should be "index.action"? Which xml configured this pattern?

This is my complete eclipse project: 157.7.141.139/pos.7z  (http)

Comment: `WebContent/index/` ? Do you mean `WEB-INF/index/`, or do you have a WebContent folder ?

Comment: Also post a `web.xml`.

Comment: Full path is WebContent/index/index.jsp, the WebContent is default folder to store jsp file when create the web project.

Comment: Now I added the full web.xml.

Comment: Check your jsp page action `index` may not be there in jsp page

Answer (score 0):

Please add all required libraries to WEB-INF/lib folder, clean the project.

Follow the image for your reference,

[image]

Comment: For text, like a list of libraries, please post only text.

Comment: All these files is in WEB-INF/lib folder already, I check files one by one, version is not same but no jar file is missing. These is the files' name, commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar,
commons-io-2.2.jar,
commons-lang-2.4.jar,
commons-lang3-3.1.jar,
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar,
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar,
freemarker-2.3.19.jar,
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar,
ognl-3.0.6.jar,
struts-core-1.3.10.jar,
xwork-core-2.3.16.1.jar

Comment: please update the following jar's - struts-core-1.3.10.jar,commons-lang-2.4.jar to the latest version

Comment: I just downloaded "Struts 2.3.16.1 ("best available")" from "http://struts.apache.org/downloads.html", and confirmed struts-core-1.3.10.jar,commons-lang-2.4.jar is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <filter>
       <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
           <param-value>user.actions</param-value>
       </init-param>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
```

Change your web.xml like this. It worked for me in 2.3.16.1 version.

```
public String index() {
        return "success";
      }
```

Replace the above code by

```
public String execute() {
        return "success";
      }
```

Comment: I updated the web.xml, and replaced the function name from index to execute, it is still not work. But I found some error message from console when I run the project, "SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/so/Desktop/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/pos/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162", is this the reason?

Comment: Check if you have the jar file struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.1.jar. This is required as per the error message.

Comment: One more question. Do you have struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.1.jar if you have it then just take it out of the lib folder and try to build again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Remove all the jar files and try downloading struts 2.3.1.1 from http://archive.apache.org/dist/struts/binaries/ then use the same JAR files. It will definitely work for your filter configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I was using external JRE.

Please check whether you are using internal JRE or not.
Internal JRE is located inside JDK.
[image]

SO in project,

GO to Build Path

-->Configure

-->Libraries

-->Installed JREs

-->Give path of jdk as shown in figure

-->Finish.

Refresh the project.